# Validator CPF e CNPJ in the same textbox (ASP.NET web application)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a textbox and I'd like validate this field according quantity of numbers entered by user. I explain it: CPF's mask is 999.999.999-99 and CNPJ's mask is 99.999.999/9999-99. I have this code, but it doesn't work.
I'd like my example like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/eL52cga5/

My code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtCPF").keydown(function () {
                try {
                    $("#txtCPF").unmask();
                } catch (e) { }

                var tamanho = $("#txtCPF").val().length;

                if (tamanho < 11) {
                    $("#txtCPF").mask("999.999.999-99");
                } else if (tamanho >= 11) {
                    $("#txtCPF").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtCPF" name="txtCPF" runat="server" Width="150px" EnableViewState="false" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ*"></asp:TextBox>`

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!!

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
        window.onload=function(){
            $("#txtCPF").keydown(function(){
                try {
                    $("#txtCPF").unmask();
                } catch (e) {}

                var tamanho = $("#txtCPF").val().length;

                if(tamanho < 11){
                    $("#txtCPF").mask("999.999.999-99");
                } else if(tamanho >= 11){
                    $("#txtCPF").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
                }                   
            });
        }//]]> 
</script>
```